# Использование битовых операторов

Tags: c++

> Напишите программу, которая читает с клавиатуры целочисленное значение в переменную типа int и использует один из битовых операторов (но не %) для определения положительного остатка от деления на 8. Деление происходит как положительных так и отрицательных чисел.

Comment: я всего лишь перепечатал задание из учебника)

Comment: @chelovechki, да оно и видно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все очень просто.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  int i;
  std::cin >> i;
  std::cout << (i & 7) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Это будет работать и для отрицательных чисел. Правда тут нужно посмотреть внимательно, какого вида остаток нужно получить. Данный код для -1 даст ответ 7. На первый взгляд странно, но вполне правильно (-1 = 8 * (-1) + 7). Если же преподавателю не понравиться, то нужно уточнить, какие именно остатки нужны.

Comment: Совсем уже не хотят подумать, а Вы за них делаете

Comment: Я целый день парюсь над этим заданием, так что ваш комментарий здесь не уместен. Не забывайте, что и Вы когда-то начинали

Comment: глупый вопрос, но не могли бы Вы объяснить почему именно (i & 7)

Comment: Потому что 8 в двоичной системе будет 1000, поэтому остаток - это последние 3 разряда.

i&7 - занулит все разряды кроме последних трех. Подумав чуточку, можно догадаться, что это и есть остаток.

Для остатков при делении на 16, нужно использовать 15 и тому подобное.
Понятно, что для остатков при делении на число, которое не является степенью 2, этот метод работать не будет.

Comment: вот теперь все понятно. спасибо большое!

Comment: @chelovechki если для Вас такое решение проблемы является приемлемым, то может быть и комментарий мой не уместен.

Comment: Для закрытия бага:

     Понятно, что для остатков при делении на число, которое не является степенью 2, этот метод работать не будет

Можно поступить таким образом:

     if((a & (a - 1)) == 0) ...

Comment: @Asen, а почему не написали (для автора), что это тоже пример битовых операций, проверяющий, является ли число степенью двойки ?

Думаете сам догадается ?

Comment: @Asen а в чем баг?

Comment: @chelovechki, это не оправдание. Вы сегодня паритесь с заданием целый день потому, что до этого целый семестр гуляли и пили "Ягу", только и всего.

Comment: модераторы, это нормально вообще?